# ayuda con uso de ciclos con arrays

Tags: java

estoy aprendiendo java estoy haciendo un programa donde pido 5 cumpleaños con nombre, mes y dia, y ordenarlos de acuerdo al numero del año y numericamente, de momento solo tengo los dias mes y nombres en 3 diferentes arrays y 3 ciclos que recorren los arrays pero me estanque por que cuando corro el programa va bien por todos los arrays de nombres y dias, cuando llega al de meses pregunta por un mes y despues se sigue de corrido y pregunta por los 5 meses s y quiero haver que pida nombre,dia y mes y asi hasta completar los 5, este es mi codigo.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class birthday {
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
    Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] words = new String[5];
    int[] month = new int [5];
    int [] num = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Birthday name?");
        words[i] = input.next();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
        for(int a = 0; a<num.length; a++) {
            System.out.println("day ");
            num[a] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
            for(int x = 0; x < month.length; a++) {
                System.out.println("number of month? ");
                month[x] = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(month));
    }
   }
  }
 }  
}
```

este es el el programa ya que lo corri

```
Birthday name?
pepe
[pepe, null, null, null, null]
day 
14
[14, 0, 0, 0, 0]
number of month? 
8
[8, 0, 0, 0, 0]
number of month? 
10
[8, 10, 0, 0, 0]
number of month? 
11
[8, 10, 11, 0, 0]
number of month?
```

al final solo recorre el ultimo array que seria el de los meses alguien me podria ayudar como puedo hacer que recorra uno por uno (nombre, dia, mes, nombre,dia mes,) asi hasta completar los 5 muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes un `a++` donde debería ser `x++` en tu tercer ciclo. Voto para cerrar por ser un error tipográfico. Tal vez el programa necesite otras correcciones, pero esa es la razón de tu duda principal.

Comment: ya lo cambie pero aun asi requiero ayuda por que sigue recorriendo el array de meses y quiero que recorra uno por uno hasta terminar los 5

Comment: Elimina los 3 ciclos, y reemplazalos por uno solo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comento, en el tercer ciclo, estás aumentando la variable a++ no la x, por lo tanto quedarás en un ciclo infinito, porque x siempre será menor que el largo del array.

El segundo error, es que tienes 3 ciclos, al hacer eso, tu programa, completará cada ciclo desde adentro hacia afuera, quedando de la siguiente manera:
En la primera iteración, solicita primer nombre, solicita primer día, y solicita los 5 meses (largo array), segunda iteración, solicita segundo nombre, solicita segundo día, y los 5 meses nuevamente, y asi sucesivamente.

Mi recomendación es la siguiente:

```
public class birthday {
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        int valor = 5;    
        Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] words = new String[valor];
        int[] month = new int [valor];
        int [] num = new int[valor];
        for (int x = 0; x < valor; x++) {

            System.out.println("Birthday name?");
            words[x] = input.next();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));

            System.out.println("day ");
            num[x] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));

            System.out.println("number of month? ");
            month[x] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(month));

        }
    }  
}
```

De esta manera, con un solo ciclo, haces la solicitud de toda la información que necesitas en cada iteración. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Si! es en lo que estaba atascado muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Genial. Saludos.